# How to take the mongodb incremental backups after setting up the replicasets

Tags: mongodb, command, backup

I am new to mongodb and I know there is no direct way for incremental backups in mongodb.

I had setup the Replicaset. after this, what are the steps that I need to follow for incremental backups

I tried the below way but it is giving the error.

`db.fsyncLock()` in secondary member

`mongodump --host <secondary> -d local -c oplog.rs -o /mnt/mongo-test_backup/1 --query '{ "ts" : { $gt :  Timestamp(1437725201, 50) } }'` in secondary member.
I don't know the exact use of this command. but somehow it is giving the error.
I stuck at this step since I am facing the issue.

The error message is below.

```
2019-05-17T14:37:18.716+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:12
```

Please help me with this.

If anyone, help me out with some other process then that is also helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way of doing incremental backups which is way simpler and way faster, create another bat file which will rename the backup file by and append a timestamp and schedule it for a time (maybe 5-10 minutes) from the backup time depending on the speed of your backup.

I did the following bat file and it worked:

```
cd C:\Users\delli5\Documents\backups
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C "ren "backup" "backup%date:/=-% %time::=-%""
```

and this was after I had scheduled another backup using a bat like the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C "mongodump -d backup -o C:\Users\delli5\Documents\backups"
@ECHO OFF
```

I didn't create replica sets but just did the normal mongodump way so you can try this out.

Cheers